# bin/ld: cannot find -l<nameOfTheLibrary> install BigARTM - CentOS v7

Tags: centos, make, gcc, libraries, c++

I am trying to install BigARTM according to this [tutorial](http://bigartm.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/linux_basic.html) on Centos 7. 
But I am getting this error:

```
/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_thread-mt
/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_program_options-mt
/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_date_time-mt
/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_filesystem-mt
/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_iostreams-mt
/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system-mt
/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_chrono-mt
/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_timer-mt
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/libpthread.a(libpthread.o): In function 'sem_open':
(.text+0x6823): warning: the use of 'mktemp' is dangerous, better use 'mkstemp'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: [bin/bigartm] Error 1
make[1]:  [src/bigartm/CMakeFiles/bigartm.dir/all] Error 2
make:  [all] Error 2
```

I installed the `'Development Tools'` using `yum`, and I found the libraries in `/usr/lib64`

```
rpm -ql boost-devel | grep '_program-\|_date_time-\|_thread-\|_filesystem-\|_iostreams-\|_system-\|_chrono-\|_timer-' 
/usr/lib64/libboost_chrono-mt.so
/usr/lib64/libboost_date_time-mt.so
/usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem-mt.so
/usr/lib64/libboost_iostreams-mt.so
/usr/lib64/libboost_system-mt.so
/usr/lib64/libboost_thread-mt.so
/usr/lib64/libboost_timer-mt.so
```

I also installed boost-devel `sudo yum install boost-devel`

For `libboost_thread` lib I ran the following commands:

```
[oshri@analytics build]$ rpm -ql boost-devel | grep  libboost_thread
/usr/lib64/libboost_thread-mt.so
/usr/lib64/libboost_thread.a
/usr/lib64/libboost_thread.so
[oshri@analytics build]$  locate thread | grep libboost_thread
/home/oshri/PycharmProjects/playground/libboost_thread-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_thread-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_thread.a
/usr/lib/libboost_thread.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/libboost_thread-mt.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/libboost_thread.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/libboost_thread.so
/usr/lib64/libboost_thread-mt.so
/usr/lib64/libboost_thread-mt.so.1.53.0
/usr/lib64/libboost_thread.a
/usr/lib64/libboost_thread.so
/usr/lib64/libboost_thread.so.1.59.0
/usr/lib64 (copy)/libboost_thread-mt.so.1.53.0
[oshri@analytics build]$  locate -e thread | grep libboost_thread
/usr/lib/libboost_thread.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/libboost_thread.a
/usr/lib64/libboost_thread-mt.so
/usr/lib64/libboost_thread-mt.so.1.53.0
/usr/lib64/libboost_thread.a
/usr/lib64/libboost_thread.so
/usr/lib64/libboost_thread.so.1.59.0
/usr/lib64 (copy)/libboost_thread-mt.so.1.53.0
```

I tried three ways:

1. To create a link (using `ln`) from `/usr/lib64/libboost_<name>-mt.so` to `/usr/lib64/lboost_<name>-mt.so` and to add the `/usr/lib64` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.
2. To create a link from `/usr/lib64/libboost_<name>-mt.so` to 
   `/usr/lib/lboost_<name>-mt.so`.
3. To add `LIBS  = -L /usr/lib64` to the MakeFile.

For example:

```
[oshri@analytics build]$ ls -l /usr/lib/\*program\*
lrwxrwxrwx 4 root root 37 Jan 19 17:38 /usr/lib/lboost_program_options-mt -> libboost_program_options-mt.so.1.53.0
lrwxrwxrwx 4 root root 37 Jan 19 17:38 /usr/lib/lboost_program_options-mt.so -> libboost_program_options-mt.so.1.53.0
[oshri@analytics build]$ ls -l /usr/lib64/\*program\*
lrwxrwxrwx 4 root root     37 Jan 19 17:38 /usr/lib64/lboost_program_options-mt.so -> libboost_program_options-mt.so.1.53.0
lrwxrwxrwx 4 root root     37 Jan 19 17:38 /usr/lib64/libboost_program_options-mt.so -> libboost_program_options-mt.so.1.53.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 468952 Nov  5 20:58 /usr/lib64/libboost_program_options-mt.so.1.53.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     34 Jan 19 17:38 /usr/lib64/libboost_program_options.so -> libboost_program_options.so.1.53.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 468944 Nov  5 20:58 /usr/lib64/libboost_program_options.so.1.53.0
[oshri@analytics build]$ printenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/oshri/PycharmProjects/EuroSalesOptimization/runtime/:/usr/lib64/
```

Answer (score 1):

On a 64-bit Centos7 virt with no particularly special modifications (`lib` versus `lib64` directories have been problematical when building on Linux in the past, hence my mentioning the arch):

```
# yum -y install git make cmake '@Development Tools' boost-devel
# git clone --branch=stable https://github.com/bigartm/bigartm.git
# cd bigartm
# mkdir build && cd build
# cmake ..
# make
... jeopardy music ...
```

Okay, it takes until 99% through the build to fail. With a verbose build we can discover the precise command (with some linefeeds manually added to avoid horizontal scrolling insanity):

```
# make VERBOSE=1
...
/usr/bin/c++    -Wall -pthread -fPIC -std=c++11 -O3 -DNDEBUG  
  -static CMakeFiles/bigartm.dir/srcmain.cc.o
  CMakeFiles/bigartm.dir/__/artm/cpp_interface.cc.o  -o ../../bin/bigartm
  -rdynamic ../../lib/libmessages_proto.a ../../lib/libartm-static.a
  ../../lib/libprotobuf.a ../../lib/libgoogle-glog.a -lboost_thread-mt
  -lboost_program_options-mt -lboost_date_time-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt
  -lboost_iostreams-mt -lboost_system-mt -lboost_chrono-mt -lboost_timer-mt
  ../../lib/libmessages_proto.a ../../lib/libinternals_proto.a ../../lib/libgflags.a
  -lpthread 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_thread-mt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_program_options-mt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_date_time-mt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_filesystem-mt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_iostreams-mt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system-mt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_chrono-mt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_timer-mt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/bigartm] Error 1
```

Not finding the C library, well now that's problematical. A relevant next question is what precise files was `ld` looking for that it could not find, easily solved with `sysdig`:

```
# sysdig -p '%fd.name' proc.name contains ld
```

And elsewhere re-run `make` and lo! static `*.a` files are being looked for according to `sysdig` (which, as `ld` already told us, do not exist). So there are at least two possible solutions here, on the one hand to not compile static, or the other to get all those various static libraries installed. Let's go with the not-static option, given handy the `BUILD_STATIC_LIBS` flag in the `CMakeLists.txt` file.

```
# cd .. && rm -rf build
# mkdir build && cd build
# cmake -D BUILD_STATIC_LIBS=OFF ..
```

Well that didn't help. Okay, let's manually edit the `CMakeLists.txt` file and turn off `STATIC` builds...

```
# cd .. && rm -rf build
# vi CMakeLists.txt
...
... make stuff again ...
[ 91%] Built target artm-static
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libartm.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgflags-static
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Whoops, looks like this project really really really wants its static libraries. Some

```
yum whatprovides '*libboost_thread-mt.a'
yum whatprovides '*libc.a'
...
yum -y install glibc-static boost-static
```

churn later and then

```
cd ..
git checkout CMakeLists.txt
... build again ...
...
SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
```

Good to know, after all that other work...

```
# yum -y install git make cmake '@Development Tools' boost-devel glibc-static \
  boost-static python-devel
# git clone --branch=stable https://github.com/bigartm/bigartm.git
# cd bigartm
# mkdir build && cd build
# cmake ..
# make
```

This sort of stuff should be moved into an RPM file, so those dependencies can all be listed instead of requiring folks to flail around with git clones and so-so docs...

Comment: Awesome troubleshooting of this build breakage! This answer is a good template on how to figure out what's breaking a build and what kind of actions to attempt in order to fix it. Great job! and +1 on your comment on RPM.